# Need to split a column in a tibble with multiple values separated by semicolon in R

Tags: r

I have a tibble in R with only one column and ~2Million rows. Each row contains multiple values separated by semicolon. The first row contains header values.
I need help to split this tibble into multiple columns.

Below is the present format:

| Value |
| --- |
| Group Name;Group Level;Member;Member_Type |
| A;0;XYZ;User |
| A;0;XX;User |
| B;1;XXY;Group |
| B;0;XY;User |

Need to convert it into:

| Group Name | Group Level | Member | Member_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | XYZ | User |
| A | 0 | XX | User |
| B | 1 | XXY | Group |
| B | 0 | XY | Group |

Comment: You can use `tidyr::separate` or you can write the file to disk and read it in properly with, e.g., `read.table()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have it read into R, then you can do

```r
read.table(text = paste(dat$Value, collapse = "\n"), sep = ";", header = TRUE)
#   Group.Name Group.Level Member Member_Type
# 1          A           0    XYZ        User
# 2          A           0     XX        User
# 3          B           1    XXY       Group
# 4          B           0     XY        User
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Value = c("Group Name;Group Level;Member;Member_Type", "A;0;XYZ;User", "A;0;XX;User", "B;1;XXY;Group", "B;0;XY;User")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: In the actual data I have 12 headers and when I executed the above code, I got the following error: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 124 did not have 12 elements

Comment: I think this is an issue of under-representative sample data. Perhaps look at rows 123-135 and see what is different about 124 to trigger that error; it sounds like either (a) it has embedded semicolons; (b) it is a malformed row that truly is broken; or (c) your file has multiple tables, and row 124 is the start of a new table with new dimensions (i.e., a multi-table file). Or (d) something else, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and line 124 seems perfectly normal with 12 values separated by semicolon. Is there a way to check broken rows?

Comment: Did you check line 125 as well? I think it reports 125 as "row 124" when `header=TRUE` (since the 125th line is row 124 after the header line is considered). Otherwise, I don't know for certain.

Comment: yeah checked ~10 line above and below line 124 but nothing seems abnormal :(